# Looking for a group email solution - need groups to be updated with php

Tags: php, email, drupal, cpanel, civicrm

We are currently using emails like group@mycompany.com to reach a select group of our staff. But so far we were using email forwarders from cpanel. (Web interface, have to get them in and out one by one)

I'd like to write a php script to automatically set up email forwarders, or automatically receive an email and send it to the proper groups. Not sure what kind of solution would be the best for us. Any tools you already use that you could recommend?

I don't have a dedicated server so we can't use cpanel's api our hosting company told us.

If that helps I'm managing my contacts and groups with civicrm under drupal. (And yeah I'd like my script to lookup those groups in civicrm and set up the forwarders accordingly)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In cpanel under mail section "Mailing listes" is a good option to do so. check it.

Mailing lists can simplify sending messages to a large group of people. You can add a group of email addresses to a mailing list to avoid typing those addresses each time you send a message. This can be very useful when sending newsletters or other updates to large groups of people. You can configure specific settings for your list once it is created by clicking Modify.

Comment: Thanks but it still looks like another web interface I would need to manually use each time there is a new member. Does it create a file or database I could modify with php?